# updated_at without created_at laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I only need to use updated_at without created_at. Is there any way to do this? I searched the entire Internet, but I didn't find it(maybe I was looking for it badly), mostly there were some old questions about it.

Comment: `timestamps` is a both-or-none deal; if you're using `$table->timestamps();` and `public $timestamps = true;` on your model, then both `created_at` and `updated_at` will be included. Any reason you don't want `created_at`? I think you could simply ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore `created_at` column, in your migration file you can do

```
...

$table->timestamps(); // remove
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable(); // add

...
```

then in your model you will add

```
...

public const CREATED_AT = null;

...
```